# Passing a value through URL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what i want to achieve ; sending ID's through URL's and printing it.

***index.html***

```
<a href="print.php?id=1">ID 1</a>
<a href="print.php?id=2">ID 2</a>
```

***receive.php***

```
<?php
    $id_q = $_GET['id'];
    print "The parameters passed through URL are $id_q";
?>
```

This above code works perfectly, I'm not able to do this with a list of ID's printed with a php command.

The below code is used to print all the PID's in the DB.How do i make every PID printed clickable ?
When I add html tags inside PHP code it throws up an error.

**print.php**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM List");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['PID'];
}
```

**edit-query.php**

```
$pid_q=$_GET[pid];
echo $pid_q;
```

Comment: Remember to check parameter before using it in sql query, because what you are doing now it's the best example of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerable functionality.

Comment: general tip: if you get an error, then tell us what the error is, and show us the code that caused it.

Comment: @iwo: there's no sql injection problem in this code. No outside data is being used in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<a href='receive.php?id=".$row['PID']."'>".$row['PID']."</a>";
  }
```

If you want to add your own text to a variable or echo, quote it and separate the variable with a "."

Comment: Probably because I href'd the wrong file and messed up a quotation mark. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="script.php?id='.$row['PID'].'">'.$row['PID'].'</a>';
```

you should do that like this

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
echo '<a href="print.php?id='. $row['PID'] . '">' . $row['PID'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you mean?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<a href="print.php?' . $row['PID'] . '">Print ID: ' . $row['PID'] . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<p id=".$row['PID']." class='clickable'>" . $row['PID'] . "</p>";
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickable").click(function(){
    $(this)...something...
  });
});
```

This is a little something you can do using JQuery if you wanted each PID to do something other than refer to another location.  It will listen on any

with the clickable class.